# Does changing openvpn to wireguard make sense?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, wireguard, open

For now I have this:

1. Vps with installed openvpn server
2. Another vps, connected to the first vps
3. 2 home networks (apartment and my country house), connected to the first vps

I want to switch to wireguard, because I need the higher speed between home networks.
I'm wondering: it it possible to reach any device from one home network to another home network? With openvpn I can easily do it with setting in the config:

```
### Local network
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

I'm not sure it's possible with wireguard or it could be implemented as well?

Comment: You'll need a lot of addtional elbow grease to even do what your current OpenVPN configuration is doing (pushing routes). WireGuard was designed for simplicity (eg: once running it runs completely in kernel on Linux) so there are tradeoffs. That said, have a look at https://github.com/netbirdio/netbird#readme (and https://netbird.io/docs/getting-started/self-hosting ). Though the authentication part might make it hard and overkill.

Comment: Also, just to state that this is not implemented with WireGuard alone, here are thoughts about it from its author: https://git.zx2c4.com/wg-dynamic/about/docs/idea.md

Comment: AFAIK, wireguard simply creates interfaces (with optional controls as to what ips can be routed through them). It is EASIER to do this on Wireguard then OpenVPN as you dont need to worry about the internal openvpn routing table. (But im fairly new to wireguard)